# Select and Variable for Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, variables

I am trying to run a select statement where I store the returned integer into a variable(saving it as an integer) and I seem to be having trouble.

My code looks something like this:

```
variable testVariable2 number;
exec :testVariable2 := SELECT wordCount FROM testTable WHERE lineNumber = 5;
```

Does anyone have an idea for how I could do this, I've tried SELECT INTO and I can't seem to get either to work?

Answer (score 0):

Adapting [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS150) example for your query:

```
EXEC SELECT wordCount INTO :testVariable2 FROM testTable WHERE lineNumber = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `select into`:

```
SELECT wordCount INTO :testVariable2
FROM testTable
WHERE lineNumber = 5;
```